# Onfocus textbox username put in textbox firstname value and textbox lastname value splitted with

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms, textbox

As start I had input fields, it worked fine with the jquery code, now I changed the input fields into asp.net textboxes because I expanded out so it inserts the data into a database. So now I need to figure out how it works with asp:textboxes.

I have 3 asp.net textboxes for first name, last name and username

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_firstname" runat="server" name="firstname></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_lastname" runat="server" name="lastname"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_username" runat="server" name="username"></asp:TextBox>
```

I don't think it's because I have the wrong jquery file
The jquery file I'm using is this:

`<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>`

```
$("#<%=TextBox_username.ClientID%>").focus(function () {
    var firstname = $("#<%=TextBox_firstname.ClientID%>").val();
    var lastname = $("#<%=TextBox_lastname.ClientID%>").val();
    if (firstname && lastname && !this.value) {
        this.value = firstname + "." + lastname;
    }
} );
```

I have researched how to get Asp.net control ID with jquery selector

`("#<%=TextBox_username.ClientID%>")`

I copied the format that was given, so it wasn't wrong.
But it doesn't work either.

I don't know how to test this if this goes wrong. I would be glad if someone could explain how I can find out if this is working or not. But it is even better if you could see the solution.

**EDIT:** I am not using masterpage - content placeholder, i am only using default webform

Comment: Use "View page source" in your browser to verify Id's and JS after the page loaded.

Comment: The Id of the Textbox_username and so on, is the same, but in the JS file, it's just saying $("#<%=TextBox_username.ClientID%>"). This is really weird, now it comes up with an error: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #<%=TextBox_username.ClientID%>

Comment: Great! that's the problem. Do you have js code inside <head> tag ?

Comment: Ugh, yes i do, but it's not affecting anything of this. I have the JS file attached in the <head> tag with the Jquery code.

Comment: Yes, i have a $(document).ready(function() around the JS code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this .aspx:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script> <!-- or 1.9 -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#<%=TextBox_username.ClientID%>").focus(function () {

                var firstname = $("#<%=TextBox_firstname.ClientID%>").val();
                var lastname = $("#<%=TextBox_lastname.ClientID%>").val();
                if (firstname && lastname && !this.value) {
                    this.value = firstname + "." + lastname;
                }
            });
        });

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_firstname" runat="server" name="firstname"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_lastname" runat="server" name="lastname"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_username" runat="server" name="username"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I do not know why, sorry. Another option , if you have a few controls like that... setting ClientIDMode="Static" ===>  <asp:TextBox ClientIDMode="Static" ID="TextBox_firstname"  and then use the same ID in your external JS.

Answer (score 1):

The operator `<%=` will only be run if the file containing it ends in *.aspx*

Files with a *.js* extension are **not** parsed by the ASP.NET engine and therefore the same code of `<%=TextBox_firstname.ClientID%>` will be rendered in the .js file in the browser.  ASP.NET will not process the *.js* file and convert this code into the actual ID of the field (*TextBox_firstname*)

The example from Mate works because he/she placed the JavaScript code directly into the *.aspx* file.  I suspect that your js code was in a *.js* file and not directly in the *.aspx* file?

Craig

Comment: Alright, that makes also sense, that asp operators doesn't work in other pages than .aspx
By "convert this code into the actual ID of the field", mean i should use the actual ID in .js file?

Comment: Yes, in the external .js file, use $("#TextBox_firstname").val();  You will also need to set the ClientIDMode="Static" as per @Mate suggestion.